List name doesn't exist in current context C#
I've been further working on my quiz game project and I've encountered another issue. I've been trying to add my question objects into a list with the questions printed in a for each loop called by a method (this is yet to be implemented).
However when I try to add an object from my class into the list (on line 20) it comes up with an error saying the list name doesn't exist in the current context. Additionally I made sure to use systems.collection.generic and my class, list and objects are all public so I'm unsure what the error is.
Here is the code:
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Quiz_for_bootcamp_project_1
{
    public class QuestionSheet
    {
        public string questions;
        public string answers;

        public QuestionSheet(string questions, string answers) 
        { 
            this.questions = questions;
            this.answers = answers;
        }

        public List<QuestionSheet> Qs = new List<QuestionSheet>();

        public static QuestionSheet Q1 = new QuestionSheet("What's 2+2?", "4");

        Qs.add(Q1 ("What's 2+2?", "4"));
    }
}


Please include the full error message

You cannot put code, qs.add for example, outside a function

Seems like somewhere you should have a "main" method that runs when your program starts, creates a QuestionSheet object, then ... well ... does something with the QuestionSheet object.

Hi here is the error message: IDE1007 The name 'Qs' does not exist in the current context.

This is just simple programming principles. You can only have declarations at the class level. Any code that doesn't include a declaration must be placed inside a method.

    public class QuestionSheet
{
    public string questions;
    public string answers;

    public QuestionSheet(string questions, string answers)
    {
        this.questions = questions;
        this.answers = answers;
    }

    public List<QuestionSheet> Qs = new List<QuestionSheet>();

    public static QuestionSheet Q1 = new QuestionSheet("What's 2+2?", "4");

    public void AddQuestion()
    {
        Qs.Add(Q1);
    }
    
}


A proper answer would include an explanation of the problem and how the solution addresses it. Posting only code to copy and paste is not sufficient.
